# databricks notebook to show schemas in a certain catalog

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, databricks-unity-catalog

I know that in the databricks notebook, we can use `spark.sql("show schemas")` to get the schemas in the hive_metastore. Since the unity catalog is introduced, I am wondering how to show the schemas in a specified unity catalog?

Best wishes

Comment: try with this 
%sql
SHOW CURRENT SCHEMA;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons it's not documented in [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-schemas.html), but it works in Databricks SQL & in DBR 12.2:

```sql
show schemas in catalog_name
```